How can I use the build branch name in the "git branch:" Jenkins Pipeline
I've tried all of these to change the branch in my steps to be the same as the branch being built.
`     steps {
git branch: '${env.BRANCH_NAME}', credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'redacted'
 steps {
    git branch: '${BRANCH_NAME}', credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'redacted'

 steps {
    git branch: '${GIT_BRANCH}', credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'redacted'

 steps {
    git branch: '${env.GIT_BRANCH}', credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'redacted'

 steps {
    git branch: '${GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}', credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'redacted'
 steps {
    git branch: '${env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}', credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'redacted'`

I get this error
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
I can hard code a branch name and it works. But then if merge my test branch "test" into master branch, it will be hard-coded to checkout the test branch, which is not what I want.
I've tried these with single and multibranch pipelines to no avail. Using a parameterized build doesn't seem to work as the params.BRANCH variable I set gives the same error message.
Is what I want to do impossible? I have searched all over the Web and found many discussions right here on Stackoverflow, but no one was trying to do the same thing.
